# Rubocop rubocop_auto_correct does not work on ST3

Tags: sublimetext3, rubocop

have a tricky issue with `rubocop` on ST3.

```
group :development do
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
end
```

It does autocorrection fine if I run command from console:

```
ir@irostovsky ~/Projects/guestready (develop*) $ rubocop app/models/user.rb -a
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

app/models/user.rb:7:5: C: [Corrected] Layout/IndentationConsistency: Inconsistent indentation detected.
    has_paper_trail
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected, 1 offense corrected
```

But silently does nothing when I tried to run `rubocop_auto_correct` from ST3 command.
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not sure it is a solution, I just closed the sublime app and run it from the project folder. My Cmd+Shift+A command which calls `rubocop -a` for current file works ok after it. PS: after deleting/creating rvm I was needed to close/open Sublime again couple times. Then it starts to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try it out.